# Why My Python Code Does Not Importing Any Variable

Tags: python, import, python-import

I want to make a snake game using pygame

I put all the variables in a special file called var

When I import the variables from the file I get the following error

`NameError: name '_Main' is not defined`

Main code

```
# Importing Files
import pygame as App
from Var import * 



# Main Loop 
while not Over:
    if _Main:    
        pass
    elif _Game :
        pass
    elif _Score:
        pass
    else :
        App.quit()
        Over  = True
    App.init()
    for event in App.event.get():
        if event.type == App.QUIT:
            App.quit()
            Over = True
    App.init()
print("---> ! OVER ! <---")
```

Var File

```
import pygame as App

Over = False 
_Main = True
_Game = False
_Score = False
```

Comment: Variable names starting with underscore aren't imported with the `*`. Just rename them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [from import syntax discards attributes starts with \_ (underscore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697264/from-import-syntax-discards-attributes-starts-with-underscore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use "from x.y import *" use import x.y why this will work.The python wont import then as they are starting with "_".Hope this works!

Comment: It don't know I did not give any negative vote